# Kettle Generic ETL Jobs

Tags: oracle, etl, business-intelligence, kettle

I need to make a generic ETL for a the maintenance of an ODS.

My requirements are:

1. I have a table T with the names of the source tables and destination tables
2. I need them to have the same data in different databases.
3. The Kettle Job must to retreive from the source table T the list of tables to move and then move data from one to another.

I've read that there is a transformation called [Metadata Injection](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/ETL+Metadata+Injection) for this purpose but I don't think I can do what I need with this transformation.

Any ideas of how to do this? I think it's a common problem. I don't want to have hundreds of transformations for each table.

Do you know a solution within Oracle?

My Kettle version is 4.4.0 and my Oracle version is 11g

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can all source tables (or destination tables repspectively) be reached using the same database connection?

Comment: Yes, and if not, a dblink could be created. But for security reasons, it could be better not to create them and using Kettle for orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template Job (JOB-X) that loads data from Table A to Table B and then call this transformation in another Job (JOB-Y) that get the source and target table information from the Table T and passes the same as parameters to JOB-X.

You can achieve this using the Job Executor/Transformation Executor.

Appending a Pentaho wiki link for Job Executor:

http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Job+Executor

Comment: I don't have Job Executor in my kettle. Could you send my an example please?